# Is it possible to write an anonymous squaring function in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

The official site shows the following function

```
square = (x) -> x * x
```

Then you can do something like

```
square(4)
```

Is it possible to do the above in a single line using anonymous function?  I'm thinking of something like the following

```
(f = do (x) -> x * x) (4)
```

My code doesn't compile but I'm hoping the intent is clear enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the application for this is but you can substitute the definition of `square` for `square` if you wrap it in parentheses:

```
((x) -> x*x)(4) #evaluates to 16
```

Comment: You can then solve Project Euler #6 in a single line :-) console.log ((n) -> (((x) -> x*x)([0..n].reduce (a, b) -> a + b)))(100) - ((n) -> ([0..n].map (i) -> i * i).reduce (a, b) -> a + b)(100)

Answer (score 1):

drop `do` may work fine:

```
#alert (f = (x) -> x * x) (4)
(f = (x) -> x * x) (4)
```

and use pure anonymous function:

```
#alert ((x) -> x * x) (4)
((x) -> x * x) (4)
```